# How to make php webpage to access the file in /root directory?

Tags: permissions, apache2, php, webserver

I am using Linux 12.04,apache and php is installed on it.I want to access a text file in /root/ folder.I am really confused with the permissions.The php script i m using

```
<?php
$file = fopen("/root/cr.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
//Output a line of the file until the end is reached

while(!feof($file))
  {
  echo fgets($file). "<br>";
  }

fclose($file);
?>
```

This script is able to access the file /var/www folder but not able to access /root/ip.txt file. Please help and explain step to step possible.

Comment: Double-check your code. You are saying /root/ip.txt in the comment but in the code you are writing /root/cr.txt

Comment: Edit your post and include the output of `ls -l /root/cr.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will forget about the security implications of doing this and will go down to business:

If you have done `ls -l /var/www` and `ls -l /root` you would have noticed that both has different permissions:

```
$ ls -l /root/cr.txt
total 2
-rw-r-----  1 root root    0 Jul  9 01:28 cr.txt
$ ls -l /var/www
total 2
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    0 Jul  9 01:28 somefile
```

The `/root` is only readable for `root`, while `/var/www` is readable by `www-data` user. Now, if you check apache process you will notice that it's running using the `www-data` user.

$ ps aux | grep apache
www-data    5133  0.0  0.2   6512  1208 ?    R+   10:04   0:00 apache

Now, you are trying to make apache running with the `www-data` user read the file. You can take three courses of action:

1. Move the file to `/var/www` and change it's permissions so `www-data` users can read it.

   ```
   mv /root/cr.txt /var/www/
   chown www-data:www-data /var/www/cr.txt
   ```

   This is the preferable method.
2. Create a symlink to the file in the `/var/www` directory:

   ```
   ln -s /root/cr.txt /var/www/
   ```

   This won't ensure that your file is being read, in some cases.
3. **This is dangerous and should not be done!** Add the `www-data` user to the `root` group, or change the file ownership so it could be read by `www-data` users:

   ```
   chown :www-data /root/cr.txt
   ## Or
   sudo adduser www-data root
   ```

   **This shouldn't be done if you don't understand the risks!**

Comment: i have added the www-data to root ,but still it's not working.The script is not able to get content of /root/cr.txt

Comment: Excellent and good warning. @user2656583 why not put the script in a cgi-bin -where- -it- -should- -be- and set apache up with a virtual host that allows executing from that path!? WHY create different methods when the normal ones that everyone else uses suffices? w h y?

Answer (score 0):

Is the file readable by users other than root? Try adding read access for ALL.

```
sudo chmod a+r /root/cr.txt
```

Comment: yes the files is readable by everyone,but that's not solving the problem